# Linq query that returns obj results after comparing an input List against a List that is a property of an object

Tags: c#, linq

I'm very new to C# and Linq so please forgive if I misuse terminology. As I tried to phrase in my title I would like to supply a Linq query with a List<string> and have it return a List of objects who have a property that is also a List<string>. The query should look at the property of the objects and return the objects whose lists contain all the values of the query list. Here's a simplified example I'm trying to set up in a command line app.

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Colors { get; set; }
}

IList<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>()
{
    new Dog() { Name = "Rover", Colors = { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Brown" }  },
    new Dog() { Name = "Spot", Colors = { "Red", "Black", "White", "Purple" }  },
    new Dog() { Name = "Spuds", Colors = { "Green", "White", "Gray", "Brown" }  },
    new Dog() { Name = "Cliffard", Colors = { "Gray", "Green", "Blue", "Purple" }  }
};

List<string> queryColors = new List<string> { "Green", "Blue" };


//Linq query that returns List<Dog> { {{Rover}}, {{Cliffard}} } since they have both "Green" and "Blue" in their Colors list property
```

I do not even know if this sort of thing is supported by Linq but I'm hoping so, though it's entirely possible I'm approaching this problem completely wrong. I appreciate any help or pointers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you want this:

```
List<Dog> result = dogs
   .Where(d => queryColors.All(c => d.Colors.Contains(c)))
   .ToList();
```

I would suggest making `Colors` on the `Dog` object into a `HashSet<string>` for faster `Contains` checks.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/LXOBR63524)

Comment: Yes this does exactly what I was hoping for as far as filtering, for my full requirements. I just had to tweak it slightly for my needs by changing the `result` to type `List<Dog>` and the  `.Select(d => d.Name)` to `.Select(d => d)` so I get the list of Dog objects that meet the criteria. This is extremely help thank you!

Comment: @Tron08 Apologies. I thought you wanted the dog names. I've updated the answer now. You don't need the `.Select(d => d)` :)